# Next.js hangs while setting initial props on server-side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to set up SSR with Nextjs.

I have following code, where I am fetching json data and binding them as initial props.

When I am in development mode all works correctly, when I deploy to the server fetching works only on client-side (when I navigate from other view).

If I try to load directly the page with fetching, server hangs, no error.

I should add that all is running inside Docker container, but I guess it should not matter at this case.

Here is code

```
import React from 'react'
import { get } from 'axios'

import Layout from '../components/Layout/Layout'
import WorkSingle from '../components/Work/WorkSingle/WorkSingle'
import DocumentTitle from '../hoc/DocumentTitle/DocumentTitle'

const Work = (props) => {
    let works = 'Loading...'   

    if (props.workData.length > 0)
        works = props.workData.map(work => (
            <WorkSingle
                img={work.image}
                url={work.url}
                title={work.title}
                key={work.title}
            />
        ))


    return (
        <Layout>
            <DocumentTitle title='Some page title' />
            <section id="work">
                <h1 className="font_title">WORK</h1>
                <div className="row">
                    {works}
                </div>
            </section>
        </Layout>
    )
}
Work.getInitialProps = async () => {
    const response = await get('VALID_URL')
    if (response && response.data)
        return { workData: response.data.work }
    return {}
}

export default Work
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, problem was that i wanted to fetch static data from the same server which is serving app, for some reason when server tried to fetch from itself it stuck, I put the resource I am fetching to another server for now and it solved problem.

I was mocking the data via static .json file, I guess when I create actual API endpoint it will work from the same server too.